# how to add formula to the cell using vb

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I need to understand how to copy a formula and append a date along with it.

I have a sheet named " Reg ALL - current" and I have some formulas written on this sheet from cells `AJ` to `BF`.

Say `AI` holds a date value as `30/04/2019`
next `AJ` will hold `01/05/2019` and `AK` as `02/05/2019` and so on until `BF`

But `AJ` is being populated from a formula like this

```
=IF(AND(OR($E:$E="END",$E:$E="Preend",$E:$E="HOLDREG",$E:$E="ISHOLD",$E:$E="WAIT"),[@[30/04/2019]]=""),$AP$1,"") "
```

and `AK` will be with

```
 =IF(AND(OR($E:$E="END",$E:$E="Preend",$E:$E="HOLDREG",$E:$E="ISHOLD",$E:$E="WAIT"),[@[30/04/2019]]="",[@[01/05/2019]]=""),$AK$1,"")
```

where two dates are appended.

So I had to write a VBA code to autopopulate the value

Date is getting added at the end. So I created a variable `sy Sdaterange` and assigned it as

```
sDateRange = ",[@[" & Range("rStart").Offset(0, 0).Value2 & "]]=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
```

as quotes do not work, I saw the ascii value and added them.

Now I am not able to add the if to a string, so couldn't proceed with code.

So I wanted to achieve this but could not

```
Start = IF(AND(OR($E:$E="END",$E:$E="Preend",$E:$E="HOLDREG",$E:$E="ISHOLD",$E:$E="WAIT")
```

From `AJ` to `BF`

1. `Change(30/04/2019) = ,[@[30/04/2019]]=""`
2. `Change(30/04/2019)& Change(31/04/2019)`

Expected: I want the VBA code to copy the formula and add these dates to them. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Strings must be in quotes. Try `Start = "=IF(AND(OR($E:$E=""END"",$E:$E=""Preend"",$E:$E=""HOLDREG"",$E:$E=""ISHOLD"",$E:$E=""WAIT"")"` (note if you double quotes (`""`) the first one will escape the second one which will now be part of your string.

Comment: I added thanks and it works.Can you tel me how to append this if statement to the variable sDateRange(which contains date strting at 30/4/2019)